# How can i call Toast.makeText() according to result of AsyncTask in protected String doInBackground method?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I fetched data from the database in AsyncTask and if it is null, I want to Toast a warning text. I tried in AsyncTask but i learned that it isn't called in a worker thread. Here is my doInBackground method:

```
protected String doInBackground(Boolean... params) {
        String result = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {   
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet( "http://191.162.2.235/getProducts.php?login=1&user_name="+UserName+"&user_pass="+Password);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                Log.d("MyApp", "Server encountered an error");
            }
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF8"));  
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString();
         if (  result == null  )        {
        //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You entered wrong values.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
             asyncTask.cancel(true);
            Intent  inte=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            inte.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
            inte.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                startActivity(inte);                                
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                             }
        return result;
    }
```

I canceled the task and create a new intent in my code. You don't care them. You see Toast.makeText.. line, I tried like this one of course it gives error. How can i do this? If it isn't called in AsyncTask, how should i call?

Comment: can you post the error please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`doInbackground` is invoked on a background thread. So you cannot update ui on a different thread other than the ui thread.

You can return the result in `doInbackground` Based on the result update ui in `onPostExecute` or use `runOnUithread` which is a method of activity class.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // toast here
                    }
                });
```

Or

```
protected String doInBackground(Boolean... params) {
// other code
return "status"
} 
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"My status is"+result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
```

Edit

As suggested by @codeMagic move you startActivity also to `onPostExecute`. Also you do not want to cancel the asynctask run when you still have code to run

Comment: Good explanation! I would also suggest moving the `Intent` code to `onPostExecute()`, also, just because you need to start an `Activity` or show a `Toast` based on your `result`. Check it in `onPostExecute()`, as suggested in this answer, and take the appropriate action. Also, I'm not sure you want to cancel a task inside `doInBackground()` when you still have code to run and it will be unnecessary if you move this code to `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Thank you it works in onPostExecute. I thought in complex way for to do that unnecessarily :)

Comment: May i ask a question about your comment ? @codeMagic Do you suggest me that If i moved the Intent code to onPostExecute(), i don't need to cancel the task ? but i want to start same activity (login page) so i have to cancel the task. Because when i don't cancel the task and the new intent started, the app crashes.Could i cancel the task in onPostExecute() ?

Comment: @elfoz you don't need to cancel the task when you finsish background computation control goes to `onPostExecute`. SO based on the value return you can either op to startActivity or do soemthing else.

Comment: If i don't cancel the task and start the same activity in onPostExecute (the user name or password don't exist in the database so the login page has to appear again), if the user want to enter values again, the app crashes. (the task doesn't start again)

Comment: you don't need to start the same activity. pop up a dialog and ask user to enter username and password if it does not exist in the database. why do you need to start the same activity. its a problem with your design

Comment: Even if i don't start the same activity, the task doesn't run again.

Comment: @elfoz I'm not sure what your issue is but you probably aren't starting a new instance of your task. An instance of an `AsyncTask` can only be run once. If you are trying to use the same one then you need to create a new instance if you need to run it again.

Comment: You may be right.Creating a new instance of the task may be useful for the purposes of my code. I'll try something about that in my code. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

The Toast messages must be called in the main/UI thread. 
The ways you can solve this are:

- Put your Toast inside the onPostExecute of your AsyncTask
- Create a wrapper of normal Toast that will run on the UI thread using:

Example:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
     Toast.make...
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

if you wanted to do this use `handler` 
so code will be

declare  `Handler handler = new Handler();` as member varible in activity class
and use following for displaying tost

```
handler.post( new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You entered wrong values.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
       }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the Handler of the main thread to the AsyncTask, and then use the Handler to schedule a task that post a toast message. Here is the java doc for the Handler class:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Basically you should create that object in the main/UI thread (and it will be automatically bound to the Looper of the main/UI thread). Then you would pass it to your AsyncTask. Then when you need to showing the message you use Handler.post(Runnable) method